# Зашифрованный ключ через Ajax на PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, время

Помогите идеей.

На странице есть кнопка, через setInterval и JS запускается таймер в 20 шагов с очень быстрым повторением. В итоге визуально это выглядит как бегущие цифры, которые по окончании останавливаются и показывают итоговое число. Получается игра на удачу!

На сервере идут вычисления, записи в бд и прочее...

С передачей на сервер проблем нет, за это отвечает $.AJAX(), но число отправляется в открытом виде и его легко подменить через консоль

```
var num = 'то самое число';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/inc.php',
    data: {                  
        sum: num
    },
    success: function(data){
        $(".block").html(data);
    }
});
```

Нужен эффект, когда после нажатия на кнопку и прокрутки всех числе тут же отображается ответ "вы выиграли..."

Подумывал о передаче php time() сразу при клике и md5() хэши вместе с числом по окончании прокрутки (два ajax запроса), завязанные на time() и кое-каких данных пользователя, но время в php статичное — обновляется с перезагрузкой страницы, а значит нужен еще один js и придется открывать еще одни данные с генерацией теперь уже и времени!

Собственно вопрос, как лучше передать это число?

Comment: А зачем вообще его передавать, если можно сненерировать его на сервере изначально?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC, https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-encrypt.php

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что при нажатии на кнопку "крутить" отправить запрос на сервер, где сгенерировать число, передать его скриптку, который визуализирует прокрутку чисел и в конце подставить ответ от сервера?

Отличная идея, спасибо за совет :)